# Is it safe to put a lithium ion battery on the wheel of a bike?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I am working on a project where I attach an LED strip, Arduino, and a power supply onto the wheels of a bike.  For the power supply I was looking at using an Anker portable charger (like this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Anker-PowerCore-Lipstick-Sized-Generation-Batteries/dp/B005X1Y7I2/ref=sr_1_13?s=wireless&ie=UTF8&qid=1492907509&sr=1-13&keywords=anker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005X1Y7I2))  I noticed that it had lithium ion battery cells though and I have heard that lithium ion can explode if it is cut.  What I am wondering is if it is safe to use that as the power supply on a bike wheel.  There is a possibility it could get hit pretty hard or cut in an accident if it got caught in the gears of a bike.  Would using AA batteries be any safer?

Comment: Some LION batteries are safer than others.  And there is the thought that a sturdy case would help.  There are just too many variables to say if it is safe or not.  Assuming by "AA batteries" you are thinking of alkaline.  Those would probably be safer.  But they may be heavier too. So now one might worry about the wheel being off balance or the batteries flying out of their holder. It [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/bike-wheel-pov-display/overview) what you are tring to make?

Comment: First, you have to define "acceptable safety factor" for your project. Hybrid-Electric & electric automobiles use lithium battery packs for their power storage and, in an accident it is possible that individual cells could be lacerated & ignite. But then again, "regular" automobiles carry around a few gallons of liquid gasoline which is very highly flammable, and explosive when mixed with the right quantity or air. ... Something to keep in mind when deciding exactly how safe you need/want to design something, compared with how functional you need/want it to be.